# Echo array based on distinct key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, key-value

I have “ordered by” a database to be in ascending country order, then descending years.  Each database record contains:  countryname, year, details.  There are many duplicate countries, but the years are different.  For instance:

```
Albania,  2000, details  
Albania,  1965, details  
Croatia, 2014, details  
Croatia, 2003, details
```

Can’t figure out how to echo the array to get results like the following where country is on one line and years & details are listed below without duplicating the name of the country:

```
Albania  
    2000,  details  
    1965,  details  

Croatia  
    2014,  details  
    2003,  details
```

Seems like I need foreach distinct country, echo year and details?

Here is my php so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT country, year, details FROM studies ORDER BY country, year DESC ");  
    //output data from each row in db  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {  
echo "   Country:  " .$row['country']. "<br />      Year:  " .$row['year'].  "    Details:  ".$row['details']. "<br /><br /> ";  
}
```

Would appreciate any help, I'm stumped!

Comment: In the future, highlight code blocks and do ctrl+k and it will format them as code.

Comment: `GROUP BY country` ought to do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, GROUP BY is not enough; The OP needs to format their output as described.

Comment: Use nested while loop maybe ? First get distinct country name, display that value and as you are iterating through the country name, pull the year and other details for each country ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a country check:

```
$newcountry = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
   if ($newcountry != $row['country']) {
     echo "Country:". $row['country']."<br />";
     $newcountry = $row['country'];
   }
  echo " Year:  " .$row['year'].  "    Details:  ".$row['details']. "<br /><br /> ";
}
```

This should work, because you have ordered your query by Country.  This is critical, otherwise you should absolutely add a `GROUP BY` clause to your SQL.

**EDIT:** to add a `<div>` around the group, you simply would change the echo sequence, checking first to see if the country has already been set once. It would look like:

```
 $newcountry = 'undefined';
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
       if ($newcountry !='undefined' && $newcountry != $row['country']){
         echo '</div>'; // only add a closing div if a new country (and not 1st)
       }
       if ($newcountry != $row['country']) {
         echo "Country:". $row['country']."<br /><div class='countryDetail'>";
         $newcountry = $row['country'];
       }// added the start of the <div>
      echo " Year:  " .$row['year'].  "    Details:  ".$row['details']. "<br /><br /> ";
    }
    if ($newcountry != 'undefined') { //make sure at least one <div> is set
      echo "</div>"; // close the last <div>
    }
```

I added the class `countryDetail` to the div, so you can use this with `toggle` in your jQuery.

Comment: Minor improvement: $newcountry = $row['country']; can be put in the `if` block to avoid void assignements. Changing `$newcountry` makes sense only if it's different.

Comment: This works perfect! However, for simplicity I didn't include html formatting requirements. Can't get a <div></div> to surround each group of years & details for the countries. I need it to show/hide with an arrow next to the country. I know the jquery works with plain html. No matter where I put the <div> in the echo statements, it surrounds each year & detail. Thanks, I'm almost there.

Comment: Modified, with your <div> request.  You could also wrap with jQuery, but I think this is easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this works perfect!! The details are now enclosed in a <div> & the jquery toggle works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested while loops. You might also want to use PDO/mysqli_ functions/prepared statements in place of mysql_ functions:

```
// get unique country list first
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT(country) FROM studies ORDER BY country";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

// iterate through result set of sql1
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))   
{
     $country = $row1['country'];
     echo "<br>";      // new line
     echo $country;      

     // get year, details for each country
     $sql2 = "SELECT year, details FROM studies WHERE country = '$country' ORDER BY year DESC";
     $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
     // iterate through result set of $sql2 
     while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
     {
          echo "<br>";      // new line
          echo $row2['year']. ", " . $row2['details']; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop party!

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    $rows[ $row['country'] ] = [ $row['year'], $row['details'] ];
}

foreach($rows as $country => $row) {
  $details = array_map(function($items) { return sprintf("\t - %s: %s\n", $items[0], $items[1]) }, $row);
  echo sprintf("\n%s:\n %s", $country, $details);
}
```